# How to make button next dynamically in asp.net but the database from sharepoint list

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-list

I want to ask, I have form quiz 
When user klik **button next**, it will appear next question and next choice
but the question and the choice from sharepoint list but i working in asp.net

can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use caml query to query the SharePoint list for the questions and answers.
Just query the next questions ID or something like that. Get the SPListitem and take the question and the answer from it.

Like this

```
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = "
        <Where>
            <Or>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />
                    <Value Type=\"Number\">1</Value>
                </Eq>
            </Or>
        </Where>";
      SPListItemCollection item = questionList.getItems(query);

// Get the question and the answers from the item and show them on screen.
```